# How do I determine if a color is closer to white or black?

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

I am dealing with images and would like to determine if a set of pixels are closer to white or black.

So given a set of **colors/pixles**, how does one determine if they closer to a white or a black?

I have tried some noobish algorithms, does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: In the RGB world, white is 255,255,255 and black is 0,0,0. It would seem you could just average out the three and determine if the result is closer to 0 (black) or 255 (white).

Comment: Yea i tried this averaging in one of my "noobish" solutions, but it did not work well.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would say that you can first convert the color to gray scale and then check if it's nearer to black or white.

First convert the RGB color value to compute luminance by the following formula

```
Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
```

Then check if the value is nearer to 0 or to 255 and choose black or white accordingly

```
color c = Y < 128 ? black : white
```

Mind that this works well if the color space is not gamma compressed, otherwise you will have to add a step before calculating the luminance which is a *gamma expansion*, compute Y, then perform a *gamma compression* to obtain a non-linear luminance value that you can then use to decide if color is nearer to black or white.

Comment: can you show me an example of how I can test to see if there gamma compression and get a proper luminance value, this method seem to fit my needs

Comment: You can't test for if gamma compression is present or not. You must know it beforehand, what gamma compression does it to "de-linarize" RGB values with a power function, if this is done on your colors than you must to the backward operation before computing the luminance, that's it..

Comment: In Android there is a built-in method that you can use: [`Color.luminance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#luminance(int)). It returns a float between 0 and 1, 0 being absolute black and 1 being absolute white.

Comment: Sadly, Color.luminance() was added in API 24.

Comment: Where did you get that weights for the formula? Shouldn't be grayscale = 0.3 * R + 0.59 * G + 0.11 * B?

Comment: @MareșȘtefan: there are multiple standards according to the media and other parameters involved.

Answer (score 5):

There are two potential meanings of white and black:

- Colour spectrum of visible light
- Human skin tones as determined by race, amount of tan etc.

The former is easy: convert to greyscale range 0-255. 127 or less is closer to black (0), 128 or above is closer to white (255).

I use the following function to convert to greyscale using luminance values (assuming an int ARGB format for input colour):

```
public static int getLuminance(int argb) {
    int lum= (   77  * ((argb>>16)&255) 
               + 150 * ((argb>>8)&255) 
               + 29  * ((argb)&255))>>8;
    return lum;
}
```

The latter definition (human skin tones) is impossible to do with a simple algorithm as it depends on light condition, camera settings, exposure etc. An RGB vlaue of (190,115,60) is probably approximately the midpoint in typical conditions

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [YCbCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr). Since Java and most computer processes colors in RGB format, you will need to do some conversion from RGB to YCbCr. There are many formulas to convert RGB to YCbCr.

Once you get the YCbCr value, you can check the luminance value (the value Y in YCbCr).

Comment: this is the answer you're looking for. 1+

Answer (score 2):

- Convert the colour to grayscale (a grayscale colour has all 3 RGB components equal, see [convert color image to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114857/convert-color-image-to-grayscale)).
- Check if grayscale is closer to black (0) or white (255)