# Given the RGB components of a color, how can I decide if it is perceived as gray by humans?

Tags: colors

One simple way is to say that when the RGB components are equal, they form a gray color. 
However, this is not the whole story, because if they only have a slight difference, they will still look gray.

Assuming the viewer has a healthy vision of color, how can I decide if the given values would be perceived as gray (presumably with an adjustable threshold level for "grayness")?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780632/determine-if-color-is-closer-to-white-or-black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively straightforward method would be to convert RGB value to [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and use threshold on the [saturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_%28color_theory%29) component, e.g. *"if saturation < 0.05 then 'almost grey', else not grey"*.

Saturation *is* actually the "grayness/colorfulness" by definition.

This method is much more accurate than using differences between R, G and B channels (since human eye perceives saturation differently on light and dark colors). On the other hand, converting RGB to HSV is computationally intensive. It is up to you to decide what is of more value - precise answer (grey/not grey) or performance.

If you need an even more precise method, you may use [L*a*b* color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) and compute chroma as `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness#Chroma_in_CIE_1976_L.2Aa.2Ab.2A_and_L.2Au.2Av.2A_color_spaces)), and then apply thresholding to this value. However, this would be *even more* computationally intensive.

You can also **combine multiple methods**:

- Calculate simple differences between R, G, B components. If the color can be identified as *definitely desaturated* (e.g. `max(abs(R-G), abs(R-B), abs(G-B)) <= 5`) or *definitely saturated* (e.g. `max(abs(R-G), abs(R-B), abs(G-B)) > 100`), then stop.
- Otherwise, convert to L*a*b*, compute chroma as `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` and use thresholding on this value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using Color.GetSaturation() which I assume does convert to HSV internally. However, speed is not a concern in this application. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @fish: You're welcome! You are right, `Color.GetSaturation()` returns the **B**rightness component in the HSB space (HSB is much like HSV which I've mentioned in this answer).

Comment: The brightness? I think it returns the saturation (that's what the documentation says, too).

Comment: @fish: oh, sorry, it was a dumb typo from me... Of course, it returns the saturation :) And Brightness/Value is of no importance at all for your purpose.

Comment: In HSV, the saturation is the difference between the highest RGB component and the lowest; calculating saturation alone is much more straightforward than finding all three HSV components.

Comment: @PeterO. thanks for the note, but this is not quite correct. Here's the formula (for values other that `RGB(0,0,0)`): 

`SATURATION = (MAX(R, G, B) - MIN(R, G, B)) / MAX(R, G, B)` 
 
Of course, calculating Hue and Value is not necessary and can be avoided.

Comment: @AlexShesterov: You are correct about the saturation; I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

r = 160;
  g = 179;
  b = 151;

tolerance = 20;

if (Math.abs(r-g) < 20 && Math.abs(r-b) < 20) {
    #then perceived as gray
  }