# Pystyle: convert this White_to_black to White_to_gray?

Tags: python

Library Being used: https://github.com/billythegoat356/pystyle

I'm using `Write.Print` for colors, is there a way i can input white to gray

[image: Black_to_white]

i was thinking it would be using the `StaticRGB`Method to create a custom color, but unsure.

```py
    Write.Print(f'''                                                          
                                         ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗██╗  ██╗ ██████╗
                                         ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝╚██╗██╔╝██╔════╝
                                         ██║  ██║██████╔╝█████╗   ╚███╔╝ ██║     
                                         ██║  ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝   ██╔██╗ ██║     
                                         ██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗██╔╝ ██╗╚██████╗
                                         ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝
                                                                                   
                                                      
 ''', Colors.white_to_black, interval=0.0000)
```

It may just be me missing something with the only documentation there is which is the source code to the github link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with [`pystyle`](https://github.com/billythegoat356/pystyle) before but if I understand you correctly, one way to achieve what you're looking for (*or almost*) is to find all the colors that are [close to black](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9780689/16120011) and replace them with gray :

```
from pystyle import Write, Colors

def black_to_gray(colors, gc="159;159;159"):
    def make_rgb(rgb_str):
        return tuple(map(int, rgb_str.split(";")))

    def luminance(rgb):
        return 0.2126 * rgb[0] + 0.7152 * rgb[1] + 0.0722 * rgb[2]

    return [gc if luminance(make_rgb(c)) < 128 else c for c in colors]
```

Output (*In Jupyter*) :

[image]